# Calculate difftime only if a column value matches in R

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

I have to find the difference between datetime in seconds for consecutive rows if the column serviceID have the same value.

dt :

| datetime | serviceID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:43 | 2000 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:45 | 2000 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:47 | 2000 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:49 | 2012 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:51 | 2012 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:53 | 2015 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:55 | 2015 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:57 | 2015 |

Output :

| datetime | serviceID | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:43 | 2000 | NA |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:45 | 2000 | 2 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:47 | 2000 | 2 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:49 | 2012 | NA |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:51 | 2012 | 2 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:53 | 2015 | NA |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:55 | 2015 | 2 |
| 2021-04-03 02:53:57 | 2015 | 2 |

How to do this? i tried this but gave error :

```
dt<-dt %>% 
group_by(serviceID) %>%
mutate(diff= as.numeric(difftime(dt$datetime, lag(dt$datetime))))
```

could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$` when using `dplyr` pipes. Also it is always safer to be explicit about the units in `difftime`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- dt %>% 
  group_by(serviceID) %>%
  mutate(diff= as.numeric(difftime(datetime, lag(datetime), units = 'secs'))) %>%
  ungroup
```

If you want to do this in `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[, diff := as.numeric(difftime(datetime, shift(datetime), units = 'secs')), serviceID]
```